# Append a loader on click event in jQuery. where loading time is calculation time in jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I am appending grid row  by clicking on expand icon . For large data set grid is taking time to generate. I add  `$("#fade").show();` but it is working after the code execute . I have some problems:

1. All dom element execute after the whole event finish
2. I need some way to execute `$("#fade").show();` first. In a click event while  `loadEnTrackReportLocationData(rowid, rel, $(this));` blocking the code
3. jQuery version is 1.8

Code:

```
 $(".k-i-expand").live("click", function (event) {
        $(this).removeClass("k-i-expand");
        $(this).addClass("k-i-collapse");

        var no_child = $(this).attr("data-depth");
        var column_list = $(this).attr("column-list");
        var rid = $(this).closest('tr').attr("id");

        var rel = $(this).attr("rel");
        var childClass = rel.split(',')[1];

        if (no_child >= 1) {
            var arraystr = [];

            for (var c = 1; c <= no_child; c++)
            {
                arraystr.push(c);
            }
           
            var i = 0;

            $.each(arraystr, function (index, value) {
                //alert("=>" + arraystr[i]);
                $('#' + childClass + '_' + arraystr[i]).css("display", "table-row");
                i++;
            });

            $('#projectSpreadsheet').fixedHeaderTable({ altClass: 'odd', footer: false }).promise().done(function () {
            }).done(function () {
                $("#clickbutton").trigger("click");
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#fade").show(); // This append on UI after 20s.
            $("#loader").show();
            alert("call in") // this call before fade show . and call instantly 

            var rel = $(this).attr("rel");
            var str_array = rel.split(",");
            var rowid = str_array[1];
            var actionName = str_array[1];
            var businessValue = '';
            var location = '';
            var costcentre = '';
            var fundName = '';
            var awardcategory = '';

            $("#ActionName").val(actionName);
            loadEnTrackReportLocationData(rowid, rel, $(this)); // this take 20s but it's executed first.
        }
    });

function loadEnTrackReportLocationData(rowid, rel, $this) {
    var ReportType = $("#ddlReportViews").val();
    var YearScenario = $("#viewReportId").val();
    var Year = $("#ddlYear").val();
    var Month = $("#ddlMonth").val();
    var Week = $("#ddlWeek").val();
    var Day = $('#datepicker').val();
    var CompYear = $("#ddlCompYear").val();
    var costCentreHierarchy = $("#CostCentre").attr('rel');
    var fundHierarchy = $("#Fund").attr('rel');
    var awardHierarchy = $("#Award").attr('rel');
    var enrolmentHierarchy = $("#EnrolmentCriteria").attr('rel');
    
    var location = $("#ddlLocation").val();
    var fundCategory = $("#RevenueStream").val();
    var fundCode = $("#RevenueCode").val();
    var enrolmentType = $("#ddlEnrolmentType").val();
    var product = $("#Product").attr('rel');
    var caloccCode = $("#CaloccCode").attr('rel');

    var EnrollmentType = $("#ddlEnrolment").val();
    var EnrollProgressStatus = $("#ddlProgressStatus").val();
    var ActionName = $("#ActionName").val();
    var BusinessLineValue = "";
    var LocationValue = "";
    var CostCentreValue = "";
    var AwardCategoryValue = "";
    var columnSkillPoint = ($("#chk_SkillPoint").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var columnCostCentre = ($("#chk_CostCentre").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var columnLocation = ($("#chk_Location").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var columnSection = ($("#chk_Section").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;

    var columnFundCategory = ($("#chk_Stream").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var columnFundCode = ($("#chk_Code").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;

    var columnAward = ($("#chk_Award").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var columnProduct = ($("#chk_Product").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var columnOffering = ($("#chk_CaloccCode").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;

    var columnEnrolmentCategory = ($("#chk_Category").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var columnEnrolmentType = ($("#chk_Type").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;

    var columnProgressStatus = ($("#chk_ProgressStatus").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var columnProgressCode = ($("#chk_ProgressCode").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;


    var columnSuppressZeros = ($("#chk_Suppresszeros").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var columnShowVariance = ($("#chk_Showvariance").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var columnEnrolment = ($("#chk_Enrolment").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var columnRevenue = ($("#chk_Revenue").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;

    var columnActual = ($("#chk_Actual").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var columnBudget = ($("#chk_Budget").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var columnForecust = ($("#chk_Forecast").prop('checked') === true) ? 1 : 0;
    var AwardList = [];

    $("input[name=ddlAwardItems_option_Id]").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            AwardList.push($(this).val());
        }
    }).promise().done(function () {
        if (AwardList.length > 0) {
            AwardList = AwardList.toString();
        }
        else
            AwardList = 'All';
    });

    // console.info(FiltersArray);
    var ProductList = [];
    $("input[name=ddlProductItems_option_Id]").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            ProductList.push($(this).val());
        }
    }).promise().done(function () {
        if (ProductList.length > 0) {
            ProductList = ProductList.toString();
        }
        else
            ProductList = 'All';
    });

    var CalocccodeList = [];

    $("input[name=ddlCalocccodeItems_option_Id]").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            CalocccodeList.push($(this).val());
        }
    }).promise().done(function () {
        if (CalocccodeList.length > 0) {
            CalocccodeList = CalocccodeList.toString();
        }
        else
            CalocccodeList = 'All';
    });

    var EnrolmentCategoryList = [];

    $("input[name=ddlEnrolmentCategoryItems_option_Id]").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            EnrolmentCategoryList.push($(this).val());
        }

    }).promise().done(function () {

        if (EnrolmentCategoryList.length > 0) {
            EnrolmentCategoryList = EnrolmentCategoryList.toString();
        }
        else
            EnrolmentCategoryList = 'All';

    });
    var EnrolmentTypeList = [];
    $("input[name=ddlEnrolmentTypeItems_option_Id]").each(function (index) {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            EnrolmentTypeList.push($(this).val());
        }

    }).promise().done(function () {

        if (EnrolmentTypeList.length > 0) {
            EnrolmentTypeList = EnrolmentTypeList.toString();
        }
        else
            EnrolmentTypeList = 'All';

    });
    var ProgressStatusList = [];
    $("input[name=ddlProgressStatusItems_option_Id]").each(function (index) {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            ProgressStatusList.push($(this).val());
        }

    }).promise().done(function () {

        if (ProgressStatusList.length > 0) {
            ProgressStatusList = ProgressStatusList.toString();
        }
        else
            ProgressStatusList = 'All';
    });

    var ProgressCodeList = [];
    $("input[name=ddlProgressCodeItems_option_Id]").each(function (index) {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            ProgressCodeList.push($(this).val());
        }

    }).promise().done(function () {

        if (ProgressCodeList.length > 0) {
            ProgressCodeList = ProgressCodeList.toString();
        } else
            ProgressCodeList = 'All';

    });
   
    var selectedRow = 1;
    var htmlbodystr = '';
    var dataString = "", tempsemesterList = [];
    
    var tempArray = [];
    
    var attrstr = $this.attr('rel');
    var columnName = $this.attr('column-name');
    var parentRowClass = $this.closest('tr').attr('data-class');

    setCostCentreFilter(attrstr, $this.attr('column-list'));

    attrstr = attrstr.split(",");

    var dataColumnList = $this.attr('column-list').split(",");

    var eachColumnList = $this.attr('column-list') +","+ attrstr[3];   
    var parentValue = attrstr.slice(4, attrstr.length + 1 - (-1 * -1));
    var BusinessLineValue = '';
    var SectionValue = '';
    var LocationValue = '';
    var CostCentreValue = '';
    var RevenueStreamValue = '';
    var RevenueCodeValue = '';
    var AwardCategoryValue = '';
    var ProductValue = '';
    var CalOccCodeValue = '';
    var EnrolmentTypeValue = $("#ddlEnrolmentType").val() +"Enrolment";
    var EnrolmentCategoryValue = '';
    var ProgressStatusValue = ''
    var ProgressCodeValue = '';
    for (var c = 0; c < dataColumnList.length; c++)
    {
        
            if(dataColumnList[c]=== 'Skill Point')
                BusinessLineValue = (BStructure.indexOf('Skill Point') !== -1) ? (parentValue[c] !== undefined) ? (parentValue[c] !== 'Unknown') ? parentValue[c] : 'Unknown' : '' : '';
             if(dataColumnList[c]=== 'Location')
                 LocationValue = (dataColumnList[c] === 'Location') ? (BStructure.indexOf('Location') !== -1) ? ((parentValue[c] !== undefined) ? (parentValue[c] !== 'Unknown') ? parentValue[c] : 'Unknown' : '') : '' : LocationValue;
             if(dataColumnList[c]=== 'Section')
                 SectionValue = (dataColumnList[c] === 'Section') ? (BStructure.indexOf('Section') !== -1) ? (parentValue[c] !== undefined) ? (parentValue[c] !== 'Unknown') ? parentValue[c] : 'Unknown' : '' : '' : SectionValue;
             if(dataColumnList[c]=== 'Cost Centre')
                 CostCentreValue = (dataColumnList[c] === 'Cost Centre') ? (BStructure.indexOf('Cost Centre') !== -1) ? (parentValue[c] !== undefined) ? (parentValue[c] !== 'Unknown') ? parentValue[c] : 'Unknown' : '' : '' : CostCentreValue;
             if(dataColumnList[c]=== 'Stream')
                 RevenueStreamValue = (dataColumnList[c] === 'Stream') ? (RSource.indexOf('Stream') !== -1) ? (parentValue[c] !== undefined) ? (parentValue[c] !== 'Unknown') ? parentValue[c] : 'Unknown' : '' : '' : RevenueStreamValue;
             if(dataColumnList[c]=== 'Code')
                 RevenueCodeValue = (dataColumnList[c] === 'Code') ? (RSource.indexOf('Code') !== -1) ? (parentValue[c] !== undefined) ? (parentValue[c] !== 'Unknown') ? parentValue[c] : 'Unknown' : '' : '' : RevenueCodeValue;
             if(dataColumnList[c]=== 'Award')
                 AwardCategoryValue = (dataColumnList[c] === 'Award') ? (Qualification.indexOf('Award') !== -1) ? (parentValue[c] !== undefined) ? (parentValue[c] !== 'Unknown') ? parentValue[c] : 'Unknown' : '' : '' : AwardCategoryValue;
             if(dataColumnList[c]=== 'Product')
                 ProductValue = (dataColumnList[c] === 'Product') ? (Qualification.indexOf('Product') !== -1) ? (parentValue[c] !== undefined) ? (parentValue[c] !== 'Unknown') ? parentValue[c] : 'Unknown' : '' : '' : ProductValue;
             if(dataColumnList[c]=== 'Cal occ Code')
                 CalOccCodeValue = (dataColumnList[c] === 'Cal occ Code') ? (Qualification.indexOf('Cal occ Code') !== -1) ? (parentValue[c] !== undefined) ? (parentValue[c] !== 'Unknown') ? parentValue[c] : 'Unknown' : '' : '' : CalOccCodeValue;

             if (dataColumnList[c] === 'Type')
                 EnrolmentTypeValue = (dataColumnList[c] === 'Type') ? (EStructure.indexOf('Type') !== -1) ? (parentValue[c] !== undefined) ? (parentValue[c] !== 'Unknown') ? parentValue[c] : 'Unknown' : '' : '' : EnrolmentTypeValue;
             if(dataColumnList[c]=== 'Category')
                 EnrolmentCategoryValue = (dataColumnList[c] === 'Category') ? (EStructure.indexOf('Category') !== -1) ? (parentValue[c] !== undefined) ? (parentValue[c] !== 'Unknown') ? parentValue[c] : 'Unknown' : '' : '' : EnrolmentCategoryValue;
             if(dataColumnList[c]=== 'Progress Status')
                 ProgressStatusValue = (dataColumnList[c] === 'Progress Status') ? (EStructure.indexOf('Progress Status') !== -1) ? (parentValue[c] !== undefined) ? (parentValue[c] !== 'Unknown') ? parentValue[c] : 'Unknown' : '' : '' : ProgressStatusValue;
             if(dataColumnList[c]=== 'Progress Code')
                 ProgressCodeValue = (dataColumnList[c] === 'Progress Code') ? (EStructure.indexOf('Progress Code') !== -1) ? (parentValue[c] !== undefined) ? (parentValue[c] !== 'Unknown') ? parentValue[c] : 'Unknown' : '' : '' : ProgressCodeValue;
    }

    var selectedRow = 6;
    var dataString = "";
    var tempArray = [];
    var isSuppressZeroEnabled = $("#chk_Suppresszeros").prop("checked");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: '/enTrack/EnTrackerEnrolmentAnalyticReportList',
        data: {

            pTimePeriod: YearScenario,
            pYear: Year,
            pMonth: Month,
            pWeek: '',
            pDay: '',
            pCompYear: CompYear,
            pCostCentre: costCentreHierarchy,
            pFundHierarchy: fundHierarchy,
            pAward: awardHierarchy,
            pEnrolmentCategory: enrolmentHierarchy,
            pLocation: location,
            pProduct: product, // This value also be replaced by grid proudct filter.
            pCaloccCode: caloccCode, // This value also be replaced by grid calocccode filter.
            pEnrolmentType: EnrolmentTypeValue.substr(0, EnrolmentTypeValue.length - 9).trim(),
            pEnrolProgessStatus: ProgressStatusList.toString(),
            pProgressCode: ProgressCodeList.toString(),
            pActionFrom: attrstr[3], pActionTo: attrstr[3],

            pGroupValue: cost_centre_heirarchy.Group,
            pRegionValue: cost_centre_heirarchy.Region,
            pRtoValue: cost_centre_heirarchy.Institute,
            pBusinesslineValue: cost_centre_heirarchy.SkillPoint,
            pLocationValue: cost_centre_heirarchy.Location,
            pSectionValue: cost_centre_heirarchy.Section,
            pCostCentreValue: cost_centre_heirarchy.Cost_Centre,

            pRevenueStreamValue: cost_centre_heirarchy.Steam,
            pRevenueCodeValue: RevenueCodeValue,
            pAwardValue: AwardCategoryValue,
            pProductValue: ProductValue,
            pCalOccCodeValue: CalOccCodeValue,
            pEnrolmentTypeValue: EnrolmentTypeValue,
            pEnrolmentCategoryValue: EnrolmentCategoryValue,
            pProgressStatusValue: ProgressStatusValue,
            pProgressCodeValue: ProgressCodeValue,
            pYearSemesterCombination: yearSemesterCombination,
            pTransactionTypes: financial_header.toString(),
            pIsSuppressZeroEnabled: isSuppressZeroEnabled
        },
        success: function (datalist, textStatus, xhr) {
            if ((xhr.status === 302) || (xhr.status === 401)) {
                window.alert('You have been logged out of the System');
            }
            else if (xhr.status === 200) { 

                var tr = 1;

                var dataArray = [];
                var tempArray = [30];
                var countSemester = 0;
                var isSemeserOne = 0;
                var isSemeserTwo = 0;

                var tempDataArray = [];
                var tempInnerDataArray = [];
                var tempInnerDataobj = [];
                var newclasslist = [];

                if (datalist.length > 0)
                    $.each(datalist, function (l, data) {
                        tempObj = {};
                        tempInnerDataobj = [];
                        tempObj['ExpandedColumnValue'] = data.ExpandedColumnValue;

                        $.each(TopHeader, function (i, header) {
                            var countrecord = 0;
                            if (header == 'Revenue') {
                                secondLineArray = revenue;
                            }
                            else if (header != 'Revenue' && header != "Enrolment") {
                                secondLineArray = subCategory;
                            } else {
                                secondLineArray = enrolment
                            }
                            $.each(secondLineArray, function (index, value) {
                                $.each(ThirdLineHeader, function (k, tline) {

                                    var className = '';

                                    if (secondLineArray[index] == 'Total')
                                        className = ' parent_' + TopHeader[i].replace(' ', '');
                                    else
                                        className = ' details_' + TopHeader[i].replace(' ', '');

                                    newclasslist.push(className);

                                    key = (ThirdLineHeader[k].replace(' ', '')).replace(' ', '') + TopHeader[i].replace(' ', '') + secondLineArray[index].replace(' ', '').split("/").join("OR");
                                    index_key = (key.replace(' ', ''));

                                    if (!(TopHeader[i] == 'AVETMISS' && (tline == 'Budget' || tline == 'Forecast' || tline == 'VS Budget' || tline == 'VS Forecast'))) {
                                        tempObj[index_key] = data[performce_col_mapping[key]];
                                        tempInnerDataobj.push(data[performce_col_mapping[key]]);
                                    }

                                });
                                countrecord++;
                            });
                        });

                        tempDataArray.push(tempObj);
                        tempInnerDataArray.push(tempInnerDataobj);
                    });
                

                /************************ Start Table Body *************************/
                tempArray = tempDataArray;
                cellcolor = $("tr#" + rowid + "").hasClass('even') ? 'even' : 'odd';
            
                // console.info("tempArray=>" + JSON.stringify(tempArray));
                htmlbodystr = '';
                alert("come In");
                for (i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
                    cellcolor = (cellcolor === 'odd') ? 'even' : 'odd';
                    dataString += '<tr id="' + rowid + '_' + (tr) + '"  child="0" data-class="'+parentRowClass+' ' + rowid + '" data-depth="0" class="'+parentRowClass+' ' + rowid + ' ' + cellcolor + '">';

                   
                    var tempHeaderArray = '';
                    if (BStructure.indexOf(attrstr[3]) !== -1) {
                        selectedHeadline = 'Business Structure';
                        tempHeaderArray = BStructure;
                    }
                    else if (RSource.indexOf(attrstr[3]) !== -1) {

                        selectedHeadline = 'Revenue Source';
                        tempHeaderArray = RSource;
                    } 
                    else if (Qualification.indexOf(attrstr[3]) !== -1) {
                        selectedHeadline = 'Qualification';
                        tempHeaderArray = Qualification;
                    }
                    else if (EStructure.indexOf(attrstr[3]) !== -1) {
                        selectedHeadline = 'Enrolment Structure';
                        tempHeaderArray = EStructure;
                    }
               
                    param = 20;
                    var spacestr = 0, ij;

                    ij = (columnName === dynamicColumnList[0]) ? 1 : 0;
                    for (; ij <= tempHeaderArray.indexOf(attrstr[3]) ; ij++) {
                        spacestr = parseInt(spacestr) + parseInt(param);
                    }

                    for (var col = 0; col < dynamicColumnList.length; col++)
                    {
                        if (col < dynamicColumnList.indexOf(selectedHeadline))
                        {
                            dataString += '<td></td>';
                        }
                        else if (col === dynamicColumnList.indexOf(selectedHeadline))
                        {
                            //console.info(attrstr[0]+"="+tempHeaderArray[parseInt(attrstr[0])] +"==="+ tempHeaderArray[tempHeaderArray.length - 1]);

                            if (tempHeaderArray[parseInt(attrstr[0])] === tempHeaderArray[tempHeaderArray.length - 1])
                                dataString += '<td style="padding-left: ' + spacestr + 'px !important;">' + tempArray[i]['ExpandedColumnValue'] + '</td>';
                            else
                                dataString += '<td style="padding-left: ' + spacestr + 'px !important;"><a class="k-icon k-i-expand " column-list="' + eachColumnList + '" column-Name="' + dynamicColumnList[col] + '" data-depth="0" rel="' + (parseInt(attrstr[0]) + 1) + ',' + rowid + '_' + tr + ',' + tempHeaderArray[parseInt(attrstr[0] + 1) - 1] + ',' + tempHeaderArray[parseInt(attrstr[0]) + 1] + ',' + parentValue + ',' + tempArray[i]['ExpandedColumnValue'] + '" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="-1"></a>' + tempArray[i]['ExpandedColumnValue'] + '</td>';
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            var temparray = '';
                            if (dynamicColumnList[col] === 'Business Structure')
                            { temparray = BStructure; }
                            else if (dynamicColumnList[col] === 'Revenue Source')
                            { temparray = RSource; }
                            else if (dynamicColumnList[col] === 'Qualification')
                            { temparray = Qualification; }
                            else if (dynamicColumnList[col] === 'Enrolment Structure')
                            { temparray = EStructure; }

                            dataString += '<td ><a class="k-icon k-i-expand " column-list="' + eachColumnList + '" column-Name="' + dynamicColumnList[col] + '" data-depth="0" rel="0,' + rowid + '_' + tr + ', ,' + temparray[0] + ',' + parentValue + ',' + tempArray[i]['ExpandedColumnValue'] + '" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="-2"></a>All</td>';
                        }

                    }

                    tr++;

                    var isAllZero = true;
                    var countYear = 0;
                    var amitnessCount = 0;
                  
                    $.each(tempInnerDataArray[i], function (index, record) {
                        //dataString += '<td class="text-align-right">' + isNegative(record) + '</td>';

                        if (newclasslist[index].replace(/ /g, '') == 'parent_AVETMISS') {
                            amitnessCount = amitnessCount + 1;
                        }

                        var style = expandItemShowHide(newclasslist[index].replace(/ /g, ''));
                    
                        console.log(newclasslist[index].replace(/ /g, ''))
                        console.log(style)

                        if (!((newclasslist[index].replace(/ /g, '') == 'parent_AVETMISS') && amitnessCount > 1))
                            dataString += '<td ' + style + ' class="text-align-right' + newclasslist[index] + '" >' + isNegative(record) + '</td>';

                    });

                    dataString += "</tr>";
                    htmlbodystr += dataString;
                    dataString = '';
                }

                /************************ End Table Body *************************/
                $this.closest('tr').after(htmlbodystr);
                $this.closest('tr').attr('child', tempDataArray.length);
                $this.attr('data-depth', tempDataArray.length);
                alert("close alert!");
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            if (xhr.status === 401)
                window.location.reload();

        }
    }).done(function () {

        fixedColumnshowHide()
    //  designTable();
        
    });
}
```

Here is the UI

[image]

Comment: What is `loadEnTrackReportLocationData` and what does it do that needs to block for so long?

Comment: There are several responsibility for `loadEnTrackReportLocationData` 

1.Get data by ajax call -- it takes 324ms

2.It appends row dynamically in UI where it takes time -- about 20s for large data set

3. i add code and picture of grid on top

Comment: The most obvious problem in that function is this: `async: false`  Never use `async: false`. It makes your asynchronous operation, well, synchronous and blocking. Once you fix that, if the rest of the function is just updating the DOM and it's taking a long time to do this with a large amount of data, you may need to consider some re-design options. The UI shown in the image doesn't contain a large amount of data. Maybe much of it is not shown right away? If so, store that data in variables you can access it and render those small pieces dynamically when they're needed later.